# Java Not crashing on double comma "malformed line"

Tags: java, regex, numberformatexception

My task at hand is to be able to process lines based on a text file from their addresses and sort them into their respective categories, "east", "west", "broadway", "avenue" and "bad ids". The code below does this 100% properly until it is faced with a malformed line that contains a double comma, while i could replace all double commas with a singular comma that doesnt entirely fix the issue as this line is to be considered "malformed" and should then be added to the badId's category but instead it causes a `NumberFormatException` Full Error and code below. What i'm wondering is if its possible to ignore the double comma in a way that doesnt cause this exception but still be able to parse through the rest of the file adding this line to the badId's array as intended.

**Text File Read From**

```
123-ABC-4567, 15 W. 15th St., 50.1
456-BGT-9876,22 Broadway,24
QAZ-456-QWER, 100 East 20th Street,50
Q2Z-457-QWER, 200 East 20th Street, 49
678-FGH-9845 ,,45 5th Ave, 12.2,
678-FGH-9846 ,45 5th Ave, 12.2

123-ABC-9999, 46 Foo Bar, 220.0
347-poy-3465, 101 B'way,24
```

**Error**

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "45 5th Ave"
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(Unknown Source)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Float.valueOf(Unknown Source)
    at csi311.HelloCsi311.readFile(HelloCsi311.java:99)
    at csi311.HelloCsi311.run(HelloCsi311.java:28)
    at csi311.HelloCsi311.main(HelloCsi311.java:240)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:267)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.symbol.JavaClass$JavaMethod.evaluate(JavaClass.java:362)
    at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.ExpressionEvaluator.handleMethodCall(ExpressionEvaluator.java:92)
    at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.ExpressionEvaluator.visit(ExpressionEvaluator.java:84)
    at koala.dynamicjava.tree.StaticMethodCall.acceptVisitor(StaticMethodCall.java:121)
    at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.ExpressionEvaluator.value(ExpressionEvaluator.java:38)
    at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.ExpressionEvaluator.value(ExpressionEvaluator.java:37)
    at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.StatementEvaluator.visit(StatementEvaluator.java:106)
    at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.StatementEvaluator.visit(StatementEvaluator.java:29)
    at koala.dynamicjava.tree.ExpressionStatement.acceptVisitor(ExpressionStatement.java:101)
    at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.StatementEvaluator.evaluateSequence(StatementEvaluator.java:66)
    at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.Interpreter.evaluate(Interpreter.java:77)
    at edu.rice.cs.dynamicjava.interpreter.Interpreter.interpret(Interpreter.java:47)
    at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.repl.newjvm.InterpreterJVM.interpret(InterpreterJVM.java:249)
    at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.repl.newjvm.InterpreterJVM.interpret(InterpreterJVM.java:222)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(Unknown Source)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**Code**

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.ArrayList;
/**
 * Hello world example.  Shows passing in command line arguments, in this case a filename. 
 * If the filename is given, read in the file and echo it to stdout.
 */
public class HelloCsi311 {

    /**
     * Class construtor.
     */
    public HelloCsi311() {
    }


    /**
     * @param filename the name of a file to read in 
     * @throws Exception on anything bad happening 
     */
    public void run(String filename) throws Exception {
     if (filename != null) {
      readFile(filename); 
     }
    }


    /**
     * @param filename the name of a file to read in 
     * @throws Exception on anything bad happening 
     */
    private void readFile(String filename) throws Exception {
     System.out.println("Processing file: " + filename); 
     // Open the file and connect it to a buffered reader.
     BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));  
     ArrayList<String> foundaddr = new ArrayList<String>();
     ArrayList<String> broadway = new ArrayList<String>();
     ArrayList<String> ave = new ArrayList<String>();
     ArrayList<String> east = new ArrayList<String>();
     ArrayList<String> west = new ArrayList<String>();
     ArrayList<String> overlb = new ArrayList<String>();
     ArrayList<String> badId = new ArrayList<String>();
     String line = null;  
     String pattern = "^\\d\\d\\d-[A-Za-z][A-Za-z][A-Za-z]-\\d\\d\\d\\d";
     String west1 = "^\\d{1,4}\\s\\b(West|west)\\b\\s\\d{1,3}\\w+\\s\\b(St|st)\\B";
     String west2 = "^\\d{1,4}\\s\\b(W|w)\\.\\s\\d{1,3}\\w+\\s\\b(St|st)\\.";
     String west3 = "^\\d{1,4}\\s\\b(W|w)\\s\\d{1,3}\\w+\\s\\b(St|st)";
     String east1 = "^\\d{1,4}\\s\\b(East|east)\\b\\s\\d{1,3}\\w+\\s\\b(St|st)\\B";
     String east2 = "^\\d{1,4}\\s\\b(E|e)\\.\\s\\d{1,3}\\w+\\s\\b(St|st)";
     String east3 = "^\\d{1,4}\\s\\b(E|e)\\s\\d{1,3}\\w+\\s\\b(St|st)";
     String broad1 = "^\\d{1,4}\\s\\b(B|b)\\B(Way|way)";
     String broad2 = "^\\d{1,4}\\s\\b(B|b)\\b(.|')(Way|way)";
     String broad3 = "^\\d{1,4}\\s\\b(Broadway|broadway)";
     String avenue1 = "^\\d{1,4}\\s\\w+\\s\\b(Ave|ave)";
     String avenue2 = "^\\d{1,4}\\s\\w+\\s\\b(Ave.|ave.)";
     String avenue3 = "^\\d{1,4}\\s\\w+\\s\\b(Avenue|avenue)";
     Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);
     Pattern z = Pattern.compile(east1);
     Pattern zz = Pattern.compile(east2);
     Pattern zzz = Pattern.compile(east3);
     Pattern we = Pattern.compile(west1);
     Pattern wee = Pattern.compile(west2);
     Pattern weee = Pattern.compile(west3);
     Pattern broadc = Pattern.compile(broad1);
     Pattern broadcc = Pattern.compile(broad2);
     Pattern broadccc = Pattern.compile(broad3);
     Pattern avec = Pattern.compile(avenue1);
     Pattern avecc = Pattern.compile(avenue2);
     Pattern aveccc = Pattern.compile(avenue3);
     // Get lines from the file one at a time until there are no more.
     while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
       if(line.trim().isEmpty()) {
         continue;
       }
       String sample = line.replaceAll("\\s+,", ",").replaceAll(",+\\s",",");
       String[] result = sample.split(",");
       String pkgId = result[0].trim().toUpperCase();
       String pkgAddr = result[1].trim();
             // System.out.println(sample);
       //System.out.println(pkgId);
       //System.out.println(pkgAddr);
         Matcher easts = z.matcher(pkgAddr);
         Matcher eastss = zz.matcher(pkgAddr);
         Matcher eastsss = zzz.matcher(pkgAddr);
         Matcher wests = we.matcher(pkgAddr);
         Matcher westss = wee.matcher(pkgAddr);
         Matcher westsss = weee.matcher(pkgAddr);
         Matcher broadways = broadc.matcher(pkgAddr);
         Matcher broadwayss = broadcc.matcher(pkgAddr);
         Matcher broadwaysss = broadccc.matcher(pkgAddr);
         Matcher avenues = avec.matcher(pkgAddr);
         Matcher avenuess = avecc.matcher(pkgAddr);
         Matcher avenuesss = aveccc.matcher(pkgAddr);
         Float f = Float.valueOf(result[2]);
       for(String str : result){
         //System.out.println(str);
         // Trying to match for different types
         Matcher m = r.matcher(str);
         // REMEMBER TO ADD BROADWAYS AND AVENUES HERE TOO AND FIX SO IT DOESNT HAVE ALL THE IDS
         if (!pkgId.matches(pattern) || !pkgAddr.matches(west1) && !pkgAddr.matches(west2) && !pkgAddr.matches(west3)
            && !pkgAddr.matches(east1) && !pkgAddr.matches(east2) && !pkgAddr.matches(east3) && !pkgAddr.matches(broad1) 
            && !pkgAddr.matches(broad2) && !pkgAddr.matches(broad3) && !pkgAddr.matches(avenue1) && !pkgAddr.matches(avenue2)
            && !pkgAddr.matches(avenue3)) {
           if(!badId.contains(pkgId)){
             badId.add(pkgId);
           }
           //System.out.println(pkgId);
         } 
           if(f < 50){
           //System.out.println(str);
           if(m.find()) {
             //System.out.println(str);
             //System.out.println(pkgAddr); 
             if(avenues.find() || avenuess.find() || avenuesss.find()){
               if(!ave.contains(pkgAddr)){
                 ave.add(pkgAddr);
               }
             }

             if(broadways.find() || broadwayss.find() || broadwaysss.find()){
               if(!broadway.contains(pkgAddr)){
                 broadway.add(pkgAddr);
               }
             }

         if(easts.find() || eastss.find() || eastsss.find()){
           if(!east.contains(pkgAddr)){
             east.add(pkgAddr);
           }
                       }

         if(wests.find() || westss.find() || westsss.find()){
           if(!west.contains(pkgAddr)){
             west.add(pkgAddr);
           }
                       }
           }        
           //System.out.println(str);
         }
          if(f > 50){
            if(avenues.find() || avenuesss.find() || avenuesss.find()){
              if(!ave.contains(pkgAddr)){
                ave.add(pkgAddr);
                if(!overlb.contains(pkgId)){
                  overlb.add(pkgId);
                }
              }
            }

            if(broadways.find() || broadwayss.find() || broadwaysss.find()){
              if(!broadway.contains(pkgAddr)){
                broadway.add(pkgAddr);
                if(!overlb.contains(pkgId)){
                  overlb.add(pkgId);
                }
              }
            }            
          // System.out.println(str);
                    if(easts.find() || eastss.find() || eastsss.find()){
           if(!east.contains(pkgAddr)){
             east.add(pkgAddr);
                      if(!overlb.contains(pkgId)){
           //System.out.println(pkgId);
           overlb.add(pkgId);
           }
           }
                       }
         if(wests.find() || westss.find() || westsss.find()){
           if(!west.contains(pkgAddr)){
             west.add(pkgAddr);
                      if(!overlb.contains(pkgId)){
           //System.out.println(pkgId);
           overlb.add(pkgId);
           }
           }
                       }
         //System.out.println(str);


         }
       }

     }

     if(west != null) {
      // System.out.println(east);
       System.out.println("West: " + west.size());
     }

     if(east != null){
      // System.out.println(west);
       System.out.println("East: " + east.size());
     } 

     if(ave != null){
       //System.out.println(ave);
       System.out.println("Ave: " + ave.size());
     }

     if(broadway != null){
       //System.out.println(broadway);
       System.out.println("Bway: " + broadway.size());
     }

      if(overlb != null){
       // System.out.println(overlb);
        System.out.println(">50lbs: " + overlb.size());
      }

      if(badId != null){
        System.out.println("Ids?: " + badId);

      }


     // Close the buffer and the underlying file.
     br.close();
    }



    /**
     * @param args filename
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     // Make an instance of the class.
     HelloCsi311 theApp = new HelloCsi311();
     String filename = null; 
     // If a command line argument was given, use it as the filename.
     if (args.length > 0) {
      filename = args[0]; 
     }
     try { 
      // Run the run(), passing in the filename, null if not specified.
      theApp.run(filename);
     }
     catch (Exception e) {
      // If anything bad happens, report it.
      System.out.println("Something bad happened!");
      e.printStackTrace();
     }

    }
}
```

**Expected output**

```
Processing file: test.in
West:   1
East:   0
Ave:    1
Bway:   2
>50lbs: 1
Ids?:   [QAZ-456-QWER, Q2Z-457-QWER, 678-FGH-9845, 123-ABC-9999]
```

Comment: *a malformed line that contains a double comma* - you should use a proper CSV parse class

Comment: That seems like a really tedious and read-to-read way of parsing through each line. Are you not able to use `line.contains("broadway")`?

Comment: Use of and understanding of regex was the point also for the various different ways that broadway could be spelled/represented such as b'way or b.way or bway

Comment: I added the text file, just realized i didnt put it in there. May make this question make more sense

Comment: @BretHasel Got it, thanks!

Comment: The error message is clear: the program takes the token "45 5th Ave" and tries to parse it as a number. What you probably want is to break this token by space and parse only the first token as a number.

Comment: that makes it make a little bit more sense but what im also confused by is why for some reason if i remove the double comma that it will then parse that line without any issues at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is in the line:

```
Float f = Float.valueOf(result[2]);
```

Here you are attempting to cast the value of the 2nd index into a `Float`.

In the first four rows of data, the casting is without issue because the values being casted were `50.1,24,50`.

However because of the 'double comma', which will actually be parsed as an empty string, the casting is now instead on `45 5th Ave`, which will then throw the `NumberFormatException`.

**Added below portion after query in comments about filtering out empty values in array:**

You can filter out empty values in the array with the following (Java 8 and above):

`String[] filteredResult = Arrays.stream(result).filter(o -> !o.isEmpty()).toArray(String[]::new);`

That being said.. **this solution is specifically for the problem that you're facing in this scenario**, and probably not a good solution.

The actual solution is to actually sanitize your data before you start parsing it.

Comment: ohhhhh okay now i see that makes sense. Is there a way that if that issue is detected instead of throwing that exception it just instead adds that line to the bad id's array and then continues on parsing through the file?

Comment: Added in a hacky workaround in the answer I gave above + some caveats...

Comment: More so im wondering if its possible to detect `if result[2] is a float` then set `float f = float.valueOf(result[2]);` to work around this issue but still maintain the code i currently have

Comment: To check if the result is a float, you could use `Float.parseFloat(result[2])`. It will throw a `NumberFormatException` if it's not a float. You could then use a `try-catch` block -- your code will continue execution after that instead of 'dying'.

Comment: By the way do accept my answer if this solves your problem. We can close this query then. You can do so by clicking on the 'tick' symbol beside my original answer. Good luck!

Comment: Will do! Got distracted attempting to solve it by using the parsefloat method but was getting caught up on the try-catch block and having issues with continuing on past that